# Why is the vector multiplication matrix of the GLM library so slow？

Tags: c++, matrix, graphics, glm

I'm working on a software renderer.And I use the GLM library for vector and matrix calculations.I found that vector times matrix takes 30 milliseconds on my Shader Class.What puzzles me the most is that when I compute the vector times the matrix in my main function alone, I get a time difference of 0 milliseconds.
I use GettickCount64 to calculate the Time difference.

finally,I appreciate you reading through my question.And English is not my first language.If you're wondering about my question or the syntax，Please ask me for more details.

The following is my shader Code.

```
class TriangleShader :public Shader
{
public:
    glm::mat3x3 normal_mat_f;
    glm::mat2x3 uv_mat_f;


public:
    TriangleShader() :normal_mat_f(0), uv_mat_f(0) {}

    void vertexShader(glm::mat4x3& vertex_mat, glm::mat4x4& M, const glm::mat3x3& normal_mat, const glm::mat2x3& uv_mat) override
    {
        normal_mat_f = normal_mat;
        uv_mat_f = uv_mat;
        vertex_mat = vertex_mat * M; //乘以视图变换矩阵

    }


    TGAColor fragmentShader(glm::vec3 bc, double& totaltime, Model& model) override
    {
        DWORD start_time = 0, end_time = 0;
        
        start_time = GetTickCount64();
        
        glm::vec2 uv = bc * uv_mat_f; //30ms
                
                end_time = GetTickCount64();
        totaltime += end_time - start_time;     



        //法向量计算光照强度
        glm::vec3 n = model.normal(uv);
        //Vec3f n = normal_mat_f  * bc;
        n = glm::normalize(n); //法线归一化

        float intensity = std::max((float)0, glm::dot(n, light)); //计算光照强度(防止光照强度小于0)

        //计算颜色
        TGAColor color = model.diffuse(uv);

        

        //加上环境光照
        return color * intensity + 5;
    }
};
```

I want to be able to compute vector times matrix in 5 milliseconds.

Comment: Are you compiling in release or debug mode? Have you looked at the GLM source code to see what it is doing?

Comment: not really sure, but fragment shader run for *every fragment*, which is way more times than in main (possibly once per frame).

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow!
What are you using to time the execution of your code? always use a good profiler instead of timers written by hand so you can get accurate and meaningful results.

Comment: I compiliing in debug mode on VS2022. I haven't looked closely at the source code, I've just looked briefly at the process running in debug mode, and I don't see any difference between a process that takes 30 milliseconds and a process that takes 0 milliseconds.

Comment: yes,I know the fragment shader run for every fragment. But I'm calculating how long it takes each multiplication.When the multiplication is in the shader, it takes 30 milliseconds to complete a single operation, but when I multiply alone in the main function, I get only 0 milliseconds of operation time

Comment: In case you really using GPU shaders (yuor code suggest not): 1. code inside shader is not using GLM at all !!! GLM just mimics GLSL syntax that is native to GLSL (no libs are used) so you can use them in CPU side code too... 2. how are you measuring the time? you know measuring CPU side time is not working for shaders and you most likely measure the whole frame or some barrier time instead of shader ... 3. I am not sure if non ASCII stuff (like UNICODE or yours `//计算颜色`) is allowed in shader code these days I would most likely remove (ranslate to english) them to avoid problems